# Snippet not working

Tags: ruby, atom-editor

So I'm searching desperately for an example of how to create multiple snippets which work. I have the following:

```
.source.ruby':
   'Passenger':
     'prefix': 'passenger'
     'body': """
       require 'debugger'
       Debugger.wait_connection = true
       Debugger.start_remote
       debugger
     """
  'debugger':
    'prefix': 'debugger'
    'body': """
      require 'debugger'
      Debugger.start
      debugger
    """
```

The first one works fine, but the second one doesn't.

What am I doing wrong that my debugger snippet is not working? Can someone please explain this??

Comment: What does not work? The integration into Atom? The generated code when you try to run it? Do you get an error? What is the error message?

Comment: @spickermann get nothing, when i type passenger it is working fine, it adds the snippet and it shows with an green arrow that it can be inserted, but when I type debugger nothing happens, I tried renaming doesn't work, the only time it works is when I change the order (when debugger is first passenger second) but then passenger is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's an issue with your indentation, everything starting from 'debugger' is indented one space less than 'Passenger' snippet. Either remove one space in every line for passenger snippet or add one in every line in debugger snippet.

This code works fine for me:

```
'.source.ruby':
   'Passenger':
     'prefix': 'passenger'
     'body': """
       require 'debugger'
       Debugger.wait_connection = true
       Debugger.start_remote
       debugger
     """
   'debugger':
     'prefix': 'debugger'
     'body': """
       require 'debugger'
       Debugger.start
       debugger
     """
```

Comment: Can't believe i spent 3 hours on this.. thanks a bunch!